# FireFox Driver not working with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, gradle

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

I have included selenium as dependency in `build.gradle`. It looks like

```
dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.3.1'

}
```

And in my test class I have included a small code as below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void Test1(){


            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/xyz/Downloads/geckodriver");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And I have created a **Testng** instance to run the test case in **intellij**.

**PROBLEM I AM FACING**

After I execute the test. I get the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: failed to lookup address information: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am not sure how should i go about debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Check path when you setProperty

> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
>   "D:\workspacess\src\config\geckodriver.exe");             WebDriver driver
>   = new FirefoxDriver();